# php.ini - Install Phalcon not appearing in PHPInfo

Tags: php, apache2, phalcon, php-7.4

I installed my own server for the very first time with the objective to test Phalcon but it doesn't seems to be enabled, or even present:

```
echo Phalcon\Version::get();
```

Returns error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Version' not found

Which could be the issue?

I'm running under Ubuntu 22.04

I installed :

1. Apache (latest version)
2. PHP7.4 using Ondřej Surý's repository.
3. Tried to install the up-to-date Phalcon5 using PECL but for a reason I ignore after a few warnings my Terminal does freez. Tried to install Phalcon5 using Ondřej Surý's repository but didn't get any phalcon.so file. I found the Phalcon documentation unclear with their hashtags, I don't know if I have to compile it or not). Finally I tried to get a pre-built phalcon.so and tried to use it.
4. I did rewrite **php.ini** to get a file I've created in **/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/30-phalcon.ini** and used to write inside : **extension=phalcon.so** & **extension_dir** to **"/etc/php/ext/"**. Placed the **phalcon.so** inside that previous folder.
5. And restarted apache2 services.

In phpinfo(), I can see **/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/30-phalcon.ini** is called but that's all.
Phalcon doesn't appear as it should.

Comment: With PHP 7.4 you must use Phalcon 4.1.3, preferably from https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/ and, very important, psr.so. If you want to use Phalcon 5, then you must use PHP 8. Follow the webserver setup docs accordingly for Phalcon 4 or 5: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/webserver-setup

Comment: Moderators probably will close your issue, so I will edit it to add a line that hopefully will keep your question alive.